# Find the fourth missing coordinate of a square in a Cartesian plane.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Question: Plot the points $P(5, 1)$, $Q(0, 6)$, and $R(-1, 1)$ on a coordinate plane. Where must the point $S$ be located so that the quadrilateral $PQRS$ is a square? Find the area of this square.

My try at it: Finding the area is easy. We can determine the distance $PQ$ between $P$ & $Q$ and then multiply it by itself. However, how do we find the point $S$?

The solution given in the website:

[image: The solution given]

I think that the person has just figured out the point from the diagram and not by using some Math (though, technically he did use Math to draw the figure and everything, but I am referring to something like a formula). I have the following questions:

1) Is there a way to figure out the unknown point $S$ using some formula?

2) If yes, can we do it by knowing only the distance formula and the mid-point formula?

3) Regardless of the answer to the above question; is there a more difficult/advanced way of doing it?

My try at the questions:

1) I thought of using the distance formula but that cancelled everything and didn't give me the coordinates.

2) I think that the diagonals of a square meet at the same point. Using this fact, we can calculate the mid-point of $RP$, say $(x1, y1)$ and then (taking $(x, y)$ to be the coordinates of the point $S$), use $(\frac{(x - 0)}{2}, \frac{(y - 6)}{2}) = (x1, y1)$. Does this make sense?

3) I feel like there's always a more advanced way, maybe you can shed some light on it?

P.S. I found something weird. By calculating $(x + 5, y -1) = (5 - 0, 1 - 6)$ (I subtracted the coordinates of $S$ and $R$ on the $LHS$ and of $P$ & $Q$ on the $RHS$), I am getting the correct answer! Am I going anywhere with this?

Comment: Consider the lines parallel to $PQ$ passing through $R$ and $QR$ passing through $P$. What do you think the point of intersection is ?

Comment: $S$? How does this help me again?

Comment: Yes.Are you asking for formula?

Comment: I think so because if I use the distance formula, I'll get $(x - 5)^2 + (y - 1)^2 = (x + 5)^2 + (y - 1)^2$ which gives $x = 0$...Wait, is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Because now that I see it, *I am* getting the *correct* value of $x$ using the distance formula. Maybe if I use point $Q$, I'll get the value of $y$.

Comment: Do you know how to write an equation of a line given two points?

Comment: Yeah. $(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)$ That is what I mentioned in the `P.S.` line. Am I allowed to use the line formula to figure out the coordinates?

Comment: Yes. Of course, Line formula will be easier too

Comment: @Mambo Though, why does this really work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
RS\parallel QP \quad \wedge\quad  RS= QP\quad \text{(property of square)}\\
\begin{align*}
\implies \vec{RS} &= \vec{QP}\\
\vec{OS} &= \vec{OR}+\vec{RS}\\
&= \vec{OR} + \vec{QP}\\
&= (-5,1) + (5-0,1-6)\\
&= (0,-4)
\end{align*}$$
which is the reason behind the weird method you are mentioning.

Comment: Will it apply to all quadrilaterals?

Comment: At least in which opposite sides are equal?

Comment: @user331377 I am using the fact that opposite sides of the quadrilateral are parallel and of the same length, so this works for parallelograms and rhombi generally.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks! Though (and I am satisfied, still), any other proof? Maybe something that doesn't involve vectors?

Comment: So, is this solution given here (it's to a different problem): http://www.slader.com/textbook/9780840068132-algebra-and-trigonometry-3rd-edition/132/exercises/63/ incorrect?

Comment: Is $PQSR$ a parallelogram, or is $PQRS$ a parallelogram?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @user331377 The difference is which of $QS$ or $QR$ is directly connected as a side of your parallelogram.

Comment: In that problem I just gave: $QS$. The diagram is given in the solution itself.

Comment: $\vec{OR}=(-1,1)$, not $(-5,1)$.

Comment: @mathlove Yes $(-1,1)$ is the coordinate given on the first line, and $(-5,1)$ is the one given in the image. And the first pair of coordinates does not form a square with $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: @peterwhy : Oh, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Systematically use the distance formula with each of the co-ordinates $ P,Q $ and $R$.

2) If you are using mid-point formula, then it should be $\left(\frac{x+0}{2},\frac{y+6}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{-5+5}{2},\frac{1+1}{2}\right) = (0,1).$

Comment: I'm using the line formula as mentioned in the `P.S.` line and also in your comment. I was wondering, why does that really work? Because both the lines are parallel and of the same length? Does it apply to all parallel lines which are of the same length?

Comment: Can you please mention what line formula are you using?

Comment: Wait, I think I get it. Since both the lines are parallel, their slopes will be the same too and using that fact, we can use $\frac{y1}{x1} = \frac{y2}{x2}$, correct? I am using the formula using where if you're given two coordinates, say, $(x1, y1)$ & $(x2, y2)$. You can find out their slopes using $\frac{(y2 - y1)}{(x2 - x1)}$ and since the slopes of two parallel lines is the same, we get the correct solution, am I right?

Comment: That is not enough. Because there are infinitely  many points which will give you the same slope. You should write the line equations and find the point of intersection as mentioned above in the comments. Then it uniquely fixes $S$.

Comment: All right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be critical, but a lot of the above is very over-complicated. Here is the easy and quick way to do this: take advantage of the fact that the relative spacings of the PAIRS of corners in any parallelogram are the same. I.e., whatever you do to get from the top left corner to get to the bottom left corner, do that same move to get from the top RIGHT corner to the bottom RIGHT corner, etc. You can literally do it in seconds, with no formulas. For instance, let's say I have these three corners: (0,3)   (6, 1), and (5, -2). When you draw this up on a graph, it is obvious that to get from (6, 1), to (5, -2),  you just do "down 3 and left 1". Do the same thing from (0, 3) and you get (-1,0). Done. No need for slopes, intersections, formulas, etc.