# Can we use slopes in order to find the missing point in coordinate geometry?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Question: Plot the points $P(0, 3)$, $Q(2, 2)$, and $R(5, 3)$ on a coordinate plane. Where should the point $S$ be located so that the figure $PQRS$ is a parallelogram? Write a brief description of the steps you took and your reasons for taking them.

Solution given in the site:

[image: Solution]

My question: I believe that the method used (equating the slopes since the sides are parallel) is wrong because of [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758377/find-the-fourth-missing-coordinate-of-a-square-in-a-cartesian-plane/1758406#comment3588280_1758399) Shouldn't the reasoning be [this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1758406/331377)

Comment: I would not call the parallelogram in the picture $PQRS$.

Comment: Let's call it $PQRS$, correct the coordinates. What would be the answer to my question?

Comment: I would call the parallelogram in the picture $PQSR$, for example. The order of the letters(vertices) should matter.

Comment: Then? Will the solution given above be correct?

Comment: Not correct because $PR$ is not parallel to $QS$. I'm saying that the drawing does not represent a parallelogram $PQRS$ as far as I know. The diagonals of a parallelogram $PQRS$ should be $PR$ and $QS$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one ways to find the fourth point of a supposed-to-be parallelogram.

Finding it via slopes is a formal and proper method but is NOT the fastest/efficient method. This can be seen from two of the answers provided. However, those methods require some geometrical knowledge and reasoning before one can choose the right tool (like finding the midpoints instead) to start with.

Unfortunately, co-ordinate geometry is basically about slopes and slope-calculating becomes one of the basic and well learnt tools for a learner. That is to say, finding that fourth point via slope-calculating is most likely the tempted try.